If I already have an instance of a super class, how can I create an instance of a child class from it?
How do I properly inherit data from an instantiation of a super class? For example, consider something I can get to work, but is confusing in its behaviour:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Self

@dataclass
class SuperClass:
  hello: int
  world: int

@dataclass
class ChildClass(SuperClass):
  kitty: int

  @classmethod
  def from_super(cls, s: SuperClass, kitty: int) -> Self:
    x = cls(s, kitty=kitty)
    return x

Now, let's see whether this works:
super_instance = SuperClass(0, 1)
child = ChildClass.from_super(super_instance, 2)
child

This produces output:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[48], line 1
----> 1 ChildClass.from_super(super_instance, 2)

Cell In[46], line 15
     13 @classmethod
     14 def from_super(cls, s: SuperClass, kitty: int) -> Self:
---> 15     x = cls(s, kitty=kitty)
     16     return x

TypeError: ChildClass.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'world'

So how do I do this correctly, without manually writing out each variable instantiation from the super class?


@classmethod
def from_super(cls, s: SuperClass, kitty: int) -> Self:
    x = cls(s, kitty=kitty)
    return x


Here, if you do not want to list all arguments for cls explicitly, instead of passing an instance s of the superclass, you need to create from s either a tuple of values which you can pass as positional arguments *args, or a dictionary of parameter names and values which you can pass as keyword arguments **kwargs.
Since you are using simple dataclasses, this is easy:

Either using dataclasses.astuple:
x = cls(*astuple(s), kitty=kitty)


Or using dataclasses.asdict:
x = cls(**asdict(s), kitty=kitty)




Ultimately, you are responsible for "disassembling" the superclass instance into a form that SuperClass.__init__ will accept. One fragile method for doing so is to simply unpack s.__dict__ to use as keyword arguments. (Fragile, because in general the contents of s.__dict__ are not guaranteed to be in one-to-one correspondence with the original arguments used to create s.)
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Self

@dataclass
class SuperClass:
  hello: int
  world: int

@dataclass
class ChildClass(SuperClass):
  kitty: int

  @classmethod
  def from_super(cls, s: SuperClass, kitty: int) -> Self:
    x = cls(**s.__dict__, kitty=kitty)
    return x


In your example, you seem to be trying to inherit data from an instance of a superclass (SuperClass) to a subclass (ChildClass). However, your approach has some issues, primarily due to the way the dataclass decorator and inheritance work in Python.
To properly inherit data from an instantiation of a superclass, you need to use inheritance. Let's modify your code to demonstrate the proper way to do this using inheritance:

Make ChildClass inherit from SuperClass.
Use the super() function to initialize the superclass part.

from dataclasses import dataclass

from typing import Self

@dataclass
class SuperClass:
    hello: int
    world: int

@dataclass
class ChildClass(SuperClass):
    kitty: int

    @classmethod
    def from_super_wtf(cls, s: SuperClass, kitty: int) -> Self:
        x = cls(hello=s.hello, world=s.world, kitty=kitty)
        return x

    @classmethod
    def from_super_works(cls, s: SuperClass, kitty: int) -> Self:
        x = cls(hello=s.hello, world=s.world, kitty=kitty)
        return x

    @classmethod
    def from_super_sane(cls, s: SuperClass, kitty: int) -> Self:
        x = cls(hello=s.hello, world=s.world, kitty=kitty)
        return x

# Testing the code
super_instance = SuperClass(0, 1)
child = ChildClass.from_super_works(super_instance, 2)
child_wtf = ChildClass.from_super_wtf(super_instance, 2)
child_sane = ChildClass.from_super_sane(super_instance, 2)

print(child)       # Expected: ChildClass(hello=0, world=1, kitty=2)
print(child_wtf)   # Expected: ChildClass(hello=0, world=1, kitty=2)
print(child_sane)  # Expected: ChildClass(hello=0, world=1, kitty=2)

In this approach, ChildClass inherits from SuperClass, which means it also inherits the hello and world attributes. When creating a new instance

I edited my question, as I made a typo and forgot to do to the inheritance. Now that should be fixed. However, this still does not work as one expects.
Also, and this is the keypoint, I do not want to do x = cls(hello=s.hello, world=s.world, kitty=kitty), because I might have many variables in my super class, and I would like to auto-inherit them.
